# Magento 1.9.x php 7 support

Tags: magento-1.9, php, ce-1.9.2.2, php-7

I run Magento 1.9.2.2 and I want to switch to php 7.0.

Is it possible and save to switch to 7.0 with this Magento install?

Comment: That is a serious problem because now small users with only 1 server simply can't set up a Magento 2.0 to do the lengthy migration (mission critical plugins).
Why?
php7-curl requires libcurl4 and php5-curl require libcurl3
and libcurl3 conflicts with libcurl4 because canonical **** up and had BOTH of them install a libcurl.so.3 AND a libcurlk.so.4 file on the system.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to migrate 1.9.2.2 from PHP 5.5 to PHP 7. Its not officially supported yet but Inchoo has found the solution to this.

They have developed Magento extension to make Magento compatible with PHP 7.

http://inchoo.net/magento/its-alive/

As of now from Magento 1.9.3.7 PHP 7.0 and 7.1 are officially supported. PHP 7.2 support is not yet official for both Magento 1 and 2.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks!! But it is currently not supported by Magento? So the best way is to wait until Magento releases an update to support it?

Comment: It is now officially supported.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, it doesn't. Magento CE 1.9.2.4 only supports PHP 5.4 and 5.5 officially. And while PHP 5.6 runs it just fine, it saturates log files with multitudes of warning messages.

**Long answer is that it's relatively easy to modify it to run support PHP7. However many extensions are still not PHP7 compatible so you're largely on your own**.

Comment: It is now officially supported.

Answer (score 0):

Magento has oficially released **PHP 7.2 patch for Magento 1** (September 2018), which means inchoo extension is not needed anymore!! if you installed it: Remove this module from your M1 store and use the official patch.

[Magento Patch for PHP 7.2](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download#download2240)

However, you will need to have your store patched. It requires **previous security patches** to be applied prior to installation. The complete requirements are listed on the download.