# Magento 1.9.3.4 PHP 7 support

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

Is it possible and safe to run PHP 7 with Magento 1.9.3.4?

I tried installing Memcached via Module Installer in CPanel, but memcached requires PHP7.

Comment: yes, we can run magento1.9.3.4 with PHP7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

**Magento 1.9.3.4** officially is not supported by PHP7 look the Magento requirements [here](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html), but **Inchoo** has found some solution [Reference here](http://inchoo.net/magento/its-alive/).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Magento 1.x oficial does not support PHP 7.Check this [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/system-requirements.html).

But supported if you follow this [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96299/magento-1-9-x-php-7-support).