# Magento 1 installation error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, installation, php-7

I am trying to **install** **magento 1** in **ubuntu 16.04LTS** with **PHP** version **7.02**. But I'm getting an error as below:

> CONNECT ERROR: Package community/Mage_All_Latest 1.9.3.7: requires PHP
>   version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>   Package community/Interface_Adminhtml_Default 1.9.3.7: requires PHP
>   version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>   Package community/Interface_Frontend_Default 1.9.3.7: requires PHP
>   version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>   Package community/Interface_Install_Default 1.9.3.7: requires PHP
>   version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>   Package community/Mage_Downloader 1.9.3.7: requires PHP version >=
>   5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Package community/Mage_Centinel 1.9.3.7: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <=
>   6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Package community/Interface_Frontend_Base_Default 1.9.3.7: requires PHP
>   version >= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
>   Package community/Phoenix_Moneybookers 1.9.3.7: requires PHP version>= 5.2.0 and <= 6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 Package community/Mage_Compiler 1.9.3.7: requires PHP version >= 5.2.0 and <=
>   6.0.0 current is: 7.0.22-0ubuntu0.16.04.1

This is the first time I'm working with magento 1. At beginning of the installation the PHP version and module check showed everything fine. But this error is blocking the installation. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Magento 1.9.X PHP Requirements

That's strange that the PHP check seemed to be fine, Magento 1.9.X i don't think is officially compatible with PHP 7.02 and requires one of the following versions:

- PHP 5.6
- PHP 5.5
- PHP 5.4

http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/magento/system-requirements.html

## Compatibility Module

You can get it working however i have a few instances running on PHP 7 and it only required some small changes and the sites have worked fine for over a year.

Check the below this may be of assistance:

[Magento 1.9.x php 7 support](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96299/magento-1-9-x-php-7-support)

Inchoo have a module that takes care of those modifications although i have not tested this.

Comment: How can I run this particual project using php 5.6 because I need php7 for rest of my projects.

Comment: I had to install php 5.6 in my server since it is compatible with both magento 1 and 2. I made it working. I have not tested Inchoo's module that you have suggested.